# Securely accessing an email address via IMAP protocol using Java Mail API

Tags: ssl, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm accessing my email address via imap protocol using Java Mail.

The server name I'm using is something like impa.somename.secureserver.net

Dose this mean I'm consuming messages using a secure channel? how can I verify this?

Answer (score 0):

If your program is using the "imaps" protocol, has set the "mail.imap.ssl.enable" property, or has set the "mail.imap.starttls.required" property, then you're using a secure channel.

You can verify what JavaMail **thinks** it's doing by enabling [JavaMail session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and examining the debug output.  It's possible to configure things so that it looks like it's using a secure channel, but it really isn't, but that's not likely to be done by accident.  For complete verification, you'll need to get a packet sniffer.